# Which board and OS to support running UWP app?

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

Currently, I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ on my hand. This is my first time having it. We have previous app running on Windows develop using WPF. Now we are changing to use linux. So for app, we need to use UWP.

RPi on hand having CentOS ARM7. Unfortunately, I cannot install dotnet core on it; neither SDK and runtime using `sudo yum`. I also try to find Windows 10 IoT Core but sadly, starting RPi 3 Model B+ onwards, Microsoft does not support it and will have compatibility issue as mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/PrototypeBoards).

Right now, I'm downloading RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot) to give a shot. I have limited information about RPi as I'm just starting it

If I'm going to migrate my WPF to UWP, what prototype board should I have? And if UWP can run on RPi 3 Model B+, which OS is recommended.

**The current WPF app is one page application which rendering the component based from settings in database and play some media.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Microsoft Doc, at the moment Windows IoT Core does not support Raspberry Pi 3B+, there are some known issues in [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/insider/rpi3bp). If the known issues does not affect your requirement, you can flash the preview image to run Windows IoT Core, the UWP app can run on Windows IoT Core, in fact, Windows IoT Core is a UWP centric OS and UWP apps are its primary app type. The document lists the supported prototype board.

If you want to run CentOS on RPi 3B+ and install dotnet core, you can refer to this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos).The new feature in .NET Core 3 is support for Windows desktop applications, specifically Windows Forms, Windows Presentation Framework (WPF), and UWP XAML.In this case you may not need to migrate the WPF to UWP.

Comment: I already to follow instruction from [CentOS 7 ✔️](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos#centos-7-) and I'm unable to install the sdk and runtime. Now,  I have download the RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661 and able to flash, bootup and run sample UWP from Windows IoT Dashboard. But I need to downgrade the Win10 SDK to be able to debug to remote device.

Comment: You may post a new issue about unable to install dotnet core on CentOS 7.